# Sql connect three tables

Tags: php, sql

I have a table1,table 2 and a table 3   where I would like to insert data from one table to another. The application is about a recruitment system.
The t1 is the table that contain a username and a password

```
t1
----------
ID  USERNAME   PASSWORD
```

The table 2 contains the basic information of the applicant

```
 t2
----------
ID  ID_t1  NAME LASTNAME BIRTH POSITION

The table 3 contains information about the skills
t3
----------
ID  ID_t1  ID_t2  SKILLS DEGREE EXPERIENCE
```

So, I want to store in t3 the ID of the t1 and the ID of the the t2. I need three tables because depending on position the system must store the values in different table.. For instance if the user choose potition for cashier system will show different fields, but if the user also wants a potision for personal assistant too the system store only the skills information.

How can I store them with the INSERT query?

Comment: You may want to look in to triggers for this.

Comment: what you have already tried,show some code

Comment: @user2673219 Use the edit feature to add the code to the original question.

Comment: which is candidate table?can u provide exact table structure? I cant relate the above given table structure with your query. the fild names are entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an INSERT ... SELECT statement can solve the problem. Although not tested, the following SQL code may can combine values from two tables into one.

```
INSERT INTO t3 (ID_t1, ID_t2)
  SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
  FROM t1, t2 WHERE t2.ID_t1 = t1.ID
```

Comment: I tried that, it seems that worked but it is not inserting tha values in the database.

Comment: I have just created tables and it worked on first try. May be there is another problem. In T3 you may have an unique index for ID field, but it is not autoincremented.

Comment: There is an error tha occured, it cannot find the id of the second table  the first table's id is stored by the session, '$t1.id=($_SESSION['t1.id']);' but I don't know what i write to find the table's2 id.

Comment: this is related to your PHP code. Your question does not include any PHP codes. You seem to ask for the correct INSERT query and above is the answer.